# Pass BIT data type in SQL Server procedure pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

I'm unable to execute a SQL Server procedure which has an input parameter as `BIT` data type.

This is my code:

Procedure parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[*procedure_name*]
(
@var1 VARCHAR(100) 
,@flag      BIT = 1 
)
```

DB connection code:

```py
storedProc = "SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC *procedure_name* @var1=?, @bit=?"

params = ('ABC',True)

cursor.execute( storedProc, params )
```

`@bit` is of `BIT` data type.

I'm getting this error when executing it:

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #6: Cannot find data type READONLY. (2715) (SQLExecDirectW);
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #7: Cannot find data type READONLY. (2715);
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #8: Cannot find data type READONLY. (2715);
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180);
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parameter or variable '@P6' has an invalid data type. (2724);
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parameter or variable '@P7' has an invalid data type. (2724);
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parameter or variable '@P8' has an invalid data type. (2724

How do I need to pass parameters which are of `BIT` data type?

Comment: `bit` expects a `1`, `0` or `NULL` values, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `bit` <>`boolean`.

Comment: Its not working with 0 and 1 as well. Getting same error

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72040931/edit) your question to include the parameter name and type definitions for your stored procedure. The mention of `READONLY` in the error messages suggests that user-defined table type parameters may be involved.

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/732